# Terminal returning directory without output everytime I run my code

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to solve a tuple problem in python and I am running my python code on terminal  but everytime I run it , It takes me back the folder I have stored it in, without any output. Here's the code :

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : 
     name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
count = dict()
fh = handle.read()
for line in fh :
lines = line.rstrip()
if lines.startswith('From '):
        word = lines.split()``
        words = word[5] 
        wordss = words.split()
        wordsss = wordss[0]


        for letters in wordsss :
            count[letters] = wordsss.get(letter, 0) +1

        lst = list ()
        for k,v in count.items() :
                lst.append( (k,v) )
                lst.sort(k)
                print lst
```

Comment: please correct the indentation in your code.

Comment: Can you add the command you are using in your terminal ?

Comment: Check the solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
name = raw_input("Enter file: ")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
hours = {}

# handle = open("mbox-short.txt")
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        hour = line.split()[-2].split(':')[0]
        if hour in hours:
            hours[hour] = hours[hour] + 1
        else:
            hours[hour] = 1

hours = sorted(hours.items())

for hour, count in hours:
    print hour, count
```

**Output:**

```
bharat@bhansa:~/Desktop/Stack$ python edit_narang.py 
Enter file: 
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

Please go through this: http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-007/cfbook011.html

Comment: i'm getting array out of index in this code . What is the problem here ?   name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
mst = list ()
for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith('From '):continue
    word = line.split(':')
    hour = word[5].split()
    mst.append(hour[0])
   
count = dict()
for letters in mst:
  count[letters] = mst.get(letter, 0) +1

lst = list ()
for k,v in count.items() :
   lst.append( (k,v) )
   lst.sort()
   print lst

Comment: I'm sorry but this code is not understandable, please post it in your question with proper identation.

Answer (score 0):

```
fh = handle.read()
for line in fh :
    lines = line.rstrip()
```

In these lines you are reading all the file contents and storing it in `fh` as a `string`. Now when you iterate over it in `for line in fh`, you are just getting individual characters in `line`, so `line.rstrip()` doesnt make much sense and neither does `if lines.startswith('From ')`.